# Selenium firewall issue "The requested URL was rejected.[...]"

Tags: python, selenium, web

does anybody of you know how to pass this issue?
I've already tried to clear the cookies :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4tt3.png

Best regards

Comment: Did you consult the administrator? We don't know your firewall.

Comment: @Legincy Which website?

Comment: @DebanjanB web.de 

and Klaus D: It is not mine, it is probably the server side fw which is making trouble.